# Do I have to save my photos to receive the reward for a codex entry?

Tags: dragon-quest-viii-3ds

Dragon Quest VIII 3ds has a sidequest where you're given a list of things to photograph with the new camera feature. Snap a picture of a target, bring it back to an NPC, and earn rewards.

You can also save photographs to share later. Do I have to "save" the photos that I'm just snapping for the codex?

Comment: I tagged this as [dragon-quest-viii-3ds] as this is essentially a remake with the same name but several distinct extras. Feel free to retag it if you see  a better solution.